# Write values to a 3D array inside a struct in C

Tags: c, multidimensional-array

I've been writing a function in C that executes 2D convolutions, and for that I need to import to it three different 3D arrays. So I declared, for instance:

```
typedef struct {
    float img[6][6][1];
} input_6_t;
```

And now I need to write values into the struct. Later I will pass that as a pointer to the function that will do the convolution.

I tried:

```
input_6_t test_image;
test_image.img = { {1,2,3,4,5,6} , {2,1,1,1,2,2} , {3,1,1,1,2,2} , {4,1,1,1,2,2} , {5,2,2,2,2,2} , {6,2,2,2,2,2} };
```

But it returns a syntax error. What would be the proper way to do this?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Right, I just noticed that, let me edit the post

Comment: wrapping array into struct makes allows one to make non-decaying array. However, passing it to a function or returning by values requires making a copy what is **very** costly in this case. Are you sure that you really need it?

Comment: I tried passing a three dimensional pointer to the function, but it didn't seem to work. The only option I saw was to serialize the 3d array to pass it and then de-serialize it, but that would take a lot of resources.
 I thought that in this example I would only pass the pointer of the array to the function, not make a copy of it.

Comment: it is usually better to use pointers to multidimensional arrays, variable length arrays from C99 greatly simplifies it. Consider posting the original problem in a separate question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to adjust initializer a bit:

```
input_224_t test_image = {
  .img = { {1,2,3,4,5,6} , ..., {6,2,2,2,2,2} }
};
```

Though the compilation it may flood you with warnings about `missing braces around initializer`.

To avoid it:
Either add braces around each scalar (a bit cumbersome):

```
input_224_t test_image = {
  .img = { {{1},{2},{3},{4},{5},{6}} , ..., {{6},{2},{2},{2},{2},{2}} }
};
```

or drop the last `[1]` dimensions from type of `img` member:

```
typedef struct {
    float img[6][6];
} input_6_t;
```

Comment: That syntax seemed to work for the declaration, thank you.
Later when I import this to the convolution function I get an error when I use something like `test_image[0][0][0] = 3;`, is that also not the correct syntax?

Comment: @Ricardo,you need to use `test_image.img[0][0][0] = 3;`

Comment: This didn't seem to work for me. The specific example I use this in is in the convolution: `P.img[a][b][k] += N.img[ii][jj][p] * M.img[m][n][k];` where P, N and M are different structs in the same format but with different dimensions. All the other variables are indexes used in the for-chain that precedes this.

Comment: @Ricardo, add more details about the original problem. Using arrays as struct member is not the best way to handle multidimensional arrays.

Comment: I will do what you said and write a different question about the greater problem. Thank you very much for the answers.