# Passing 3d arrays to a convolution function in C

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, convolution

I need to do a function that executes a 2D convolution and for that I need to pass to it a couple of 3d arrays. However I've been told my method is not an ideal way to do this.

First, I declare the variables:

```
typedef struct {
    float img[224][224][3];
} input_224_t;

typedef struct {
    float img[112][112][32];
} input_112_t;

typedef struct {
    float img[3][3][32];
} weightsL1_t;
```

Then, the convolution looks like this:

```
void convolution(input_224_t* N, weightsL1_t* M, input_112_t* P, int size, int ksize, int channels, int filters, int stride)
{
    // Effectively pads the image before convolution. Technically also works for pointwise, but it's inefficient.
    // find center position of kernel (half of kernel size)
    int kcenter = ksize / 2;

    // Declare output indexes
    int a = 0;
    int b = -1;

    for (int k = 0; k < filters; ++k)                   // filters
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i = i + stride)       // rows
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < size; j = j + stride)   // columns
            {
                b++;
                if (b == ksize) {b=0;a++;}              // Increment output index
                for (int m = 0; m < ksize; ++m)         // kernel rows
                {
                    for (int n = 0; n < ksize; ++n)     // kernel columns
                    {
                        // Index of input signal, used for checking boundary
                        int ii = i + (m - kcenter);
                        int jj = j + (n - kcenter);

                        // Ignore input samples which are out of bound
                        if (ii >= 0 && ii < size && jj >= 0 && jj < size) {
                            for (int p = 0; p < channels; ++p)  // channels
                            {
                                P.img[a][b][k] += N.img[ii][jj][p] * M.img[m][n][k];    // convolve
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

(This returns "field 'img' could not be resolved" at the "convolve" line)

I then import the values into the correct structs (which was a previous question of mine which has been answered: [Write values to a 3D array inside a struct in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69456732/write-values-to-a-3d-array-inside-a-struct-in-c)) and I call the function like this:

```
convolution(test_image, test_filter, test_result, 6, 3, 1, 1, 2);
```

I have been told in my previous question that this is not an ideal way to handle 3D arrays, and that it may use a lot more memory than I intend. This is a very memory-intensive process, and this will run in an embedded system, so optimizing memory allocation is paramount.

My objective, if possible, is to *only allocate one of each of these 3D arrays at any point in time* as to not use unnecessary memory, and do it in a way that this space can be freed at a later point.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: should kernel be 4 dimensional, `float[3][3][3][32]`. Each output channel should use a separate kernel?

Comment: Don't use `_t` for your typedef suffix.  https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Reserved-Names.html

Comment: @tstanisl You're right, 2D Convolution has 4-dim kernels. I had looked at the weights I generated and assumed the contrary, but you're correct.

Comment: @WilliamPursell Really? I was taught this was a good practice, apparently it's much the opposite. Thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use Variable Length Arrays as function parameters.

```c
void convolve(int isize,  // width/height of input (224)
              int osize,  // width/height of output (112)
              int ksize,  // width/height of kernel (3)
              int stride, // shift between input pixels, between consecutive outputs
              int pad,    // offset between (0,0) pixels between input and output
              int idepth, int odepth, // number of input and output channels
              float idata[isize][isize][idepth],
              float odata[osize][osize][odepth],
              float kdata[idepth][ksize][ksize][odepth])

{
  // iterate over the output
  for (int oy = 0; oy < osize; ++oy) {
  for (int ox = 0; ox < osize; ++ox) {
  for (int od = 0; od < odepth; ++od) {
      odata[oy][ox][od] = 0;
      for (int ky = 0; ky < ksize; ++ky) {
      for (int kx = 0; kx < ksize; ++kx) {
          // map position in output and kernel to the input
          int iy = stride * oy + ky - pad;
          int ix = stride * ox + kx - pad;
          // use only valid inputs
          if (iy >= 0 && iy < isize && ix >= 0 && ix < isize)
              for (int id = 0; id < idepth; ++id)
                  odata[oy][ox][od] += kdata[id][ky][kx][od] * idata[iy][ix][id];
      }}
  }}}
}
```

Typical usage would be:

```
// allocate input
float (*idata)[224][3] = calloc(224, sizeof *idata);
// fill input using idata[y][x][d] syntax

// allocate kernel
float (*kdata)[3][3][32] = calloc(3, sizeof *kdata);
// fill kernel

// allocate output
float (*odata)[112][32] = calloc(112, sizeof *odata);

convolve(224, 112, 3, // input, output, kernel size
         2, // stride
         1, // pad input by one pixel what will center the kernel
         3, 32, // number of input and output channels
         idata, odata, kdata);

// free memory if it is no longer used
free(idata); free(odata); free(kdata);
```

The multidimentional arrays could be allocated with:

```
float (*arr)[10][20][30] = malloc(sizeof *arr);
```

however accessing elements is a bit cumbersome due to syntax `(*arr)[i][j][j]`. Therefore it is simple to use a pointer to the first element of array and allocate multiple subarrays at this pointer.

```
float (*arr)[20][30] = malloc(10 * sizeof *arr);
```

or with `calloc()` with automated zeroing and avoiding overflows.

```
float (*arr)[20][30] = calloc(10, sizeof *arr);
```

---

BTW. I suggest to reorder dimensions of the kernel to ODEPTH x KSIZE x KSIZE x IDEPTH. This would make iterating over the kernel more cache-friendly.

Comment: That is a very interesting way to solve this. But I have a few questions about it. First of all, you use the variables 'yx' and later 'id' and those aren't defined. Second, when you allocate the input, kernel and output they all have one less dimension than they should. This looks intentional, I'm guessing you would be able to allocate all the data anyways. Can you tell me how you would import that data in this case?

Comment: @Ricardo, sorry, there were a few typos, see the updated answer

Comment: I also think you forgot to put the stride in the call to the function, but besides that it looks great. I didn't think about iterating over the output instead, that's much more efficient. I am also getting a warning on the call to the function: "passing argument 10 of ‘convolve’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]" and also for argument 9. Is that a problem?

Comment: @Ricardo, yes.. args were swapped. Fixed

Comment: So, for instance, if I wanted to assign the value of 3 to [0][0][0] of the input, what command would I use? Something like `idata[0][0][0] = 3`? Also, in this code, you assign data as [y][x][d], where y, then, would be the column index and x is the line index, correct?

Comment: @Ricardo, `idata[0][0][0] = 3` is correct. `y` are rows (lines) and `x` are columns. It is idiomatic to C to put `y` index *before* `x`. This way all columns within one row would be placed on consecutive memory locations. This improves cache efficiency and gives opportunities for vectorization

Comment: To expand on this... if I declare a variable as `float (*arr)[x][y] = calloc(z, sizeof *arr);` that makes an array `arr[z][x][y]` is that correct?

Comment: @Ricardo, almost. It allocates the array of type `float[z][x][y]` and sets `arr` to point to *the first* row (element of type `float[x][y]`) of this array.

Comment: I tested the code out with an example and it worked perfectly, thanks again.